# add property to many lists rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create property . Then add it on many lists. One Property can  be on many list.

here is my models:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propertyships
  has_many :properties, :through => :propertyships
end

class Propertyship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propertyships
  has_many :lists, :through => :propertyships
end
```

properties/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @property do |f| %>
    <% List.all.each do |list| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "property[list_ids][]", list.id,@property.list_ids.include?(list.id) %>
        <%= list.name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

property is not adding to lists.
what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) instead of manually creating the inputs:

```
<%= form_for @property do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:list_ids, List.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Whitelisting the params is a bit special since `params[:property][:list_ids]` will contain an array:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    # ...
  end

  # ...

  private

    def property_params
       params.require(:property)
             .permit(:foo, :bar, list_ids: [])
    end
end
```